# Google sign-in issue with AWS Cognito powered UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So I'm using AWS Cognito's Federated Identity Providers type pool to provide for Google and Amazon Sign-In into my application along with the normal Cognito Sign-in.

The traditional Cognito pool works perfectly fine where I can see the registered users. However, whenever I try to login via Google / Amazon, there's something going on.

**For Google Sign-in :** Upon clicking sign-in, it opens up the Oauth consent window but after selecting the required mail-id, it doesn't actually store it in the users pool. The search bar displays as:

```
http://localhost:8080/app?error_description=attributes+required%3A+%5Bname%5D&error=invalid_request
```

After which the call-back URL is opened, effectively without authentication.

**For Amazon Sign-in:** No consent window nor account selection window, just redirection to call back URL.

```
http://localhost:8080/app?error_description=An+unknown+scope+was+requested%3B+error%3Dinvalid_scope&error=invalid_scope
```

I'm only requesting **email & name** under scopes.
[image: Google]

[image: Amazon]

Can someone help me understand what am I missing here.